# Working with Trigonometric Functions SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a WebApi project with Dapper, and I have the table Products :

```
[Key]
public int idProducts { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public float Latitude { get; set; }
public float Longitude { get; set; }
public int ProductsItems { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

And I need to calculate the distance from point A to B and check if is less then 1km which I already did, but in C#

```
private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit)
    {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * 
            Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat2)) +
            Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * 
            Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
            Math.Cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.Acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        dist = dist * 1.609344;
        return (dist);
    }
    private static double deg2rad(double deg)
    {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }
    private static double rad2deg(double rad)
    {
        return (rad / Math.PI * 180.0);
    }
```

And `bool isLess = distance(-8.157908, -34.931675, -8.164891, -34.919033, 'K') < 1`

But that way I would have to do `select * from Products`, get all results `AsList()` and make a loop to get each item and check if the distance From the A to B is valid and its not Practical! I'm not used to make these kinda of queries with Math Involved.

How to create a query where I could pass the Lat and Long from Point A and make that math and return just a list of valid Items ?

Comment: Cannot this be processed as a query in the database? This could be rewritten in SQL quite easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To slightly improve John's answer, this is what you could do:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY
    , Lat FLOAT
    , Lon FLOAT
    , Location AS GEOGRAPHY::Point(Lat, Lon, 4326));

INSERT INTO YourTable (ID, Lat, Lon)
VALUES
    (1,-8.157908, -34.931675)
    , (2,-8.164891, -34.919033)
    , (3,-8.159999, -34.939999);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION GetCloserThanOneKilometer (
    @Lat FLOAT
    , @Lon FLOAT
    , @Distance FLOAT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE GEOGRAPHY::Point(@Lat, @Lon, 4326).STDistance(Location) <= @Distance;
```

You'll have a calculated column that will store coordinates. So in order to abstract and simplify querying you can create a inline function which I skillfully named `GetCloserThanOneKilometer` and then run query as follows to get data based on your given latitude and longitude and distance that has to be lower than your input (`@Distance` param):

```
SELECT *
FROM GetCloserThanOneKilometer(-8.157908, -34.931675, 1000);
GO
```

Comment: Nice improvement... Clear, clean example +1

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks Evaldas and John!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GEOGRAPHY` in SQL Server.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Lat float,Lng float)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,-8.157908, -34.931675)
,(2,-8.164891, -34.919033)  -- Will be exclued ... 1,592 meters away
,(3,-8.159999, -34.939999)  -- Forced to be < 1000 meters

DECLARE @Origin GEOGRAPHY
DECLARE @Fetch int = 1

Select @Origin =GEOGRAPHY::Point([Lat], [Lng], 4326) from @YourTable WHERE ID=@Fetch

Select *
      ,Meters = @Origin.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point([Lat], [Lng], 4326))
 From  @YourTable
 Where @Origin.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point([Lat], [Lng], 4326)) <= 1000
 Order By Meters
```

**Returns**

```
ID   Lat        Lng           Meters
1   -8.157908   -34.931675    0                   --<< Orgin/Fetch
3   -8.159999   -34.939999    946.007737339573
```

> **EDIT - If you want to create your own calculation**

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[udf-Geo-Meters](@Lat1 FLOAT, @Lng1 FLOAT, @Lat2 FLOAT, @Lng2 FLOAT)
Returns Float as
Begin
    Return ACOS(SIN(PI()*@Lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@Lat2/180.0)+COS(PI()*@Lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*@Lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*@Lng2/180.0-PI()*@Lng1/180.0)) * 6371008.8
    -- 6.371 mean radius of earth in meters
End
```

I should add, the UDF calculation is virtually spot-on with the Google Maps calculation.

Comment: You can also create a computed column to store Location instead of having to calculate that each time. :)

Comment: It is something like that, but look at this line in C# `double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit)` The lat1 and lon1 are the values that I'm gonna pass grammatically(It will be different every call) and the lat2 and lon2 they are already stored into this table, something like "Check if the Lat and Long passed is less then 1km from all these values from this Table and return only those who are valid".

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Very true, and I should have pointed that out.   I was going for a simple illustration.